# Git switching branches issue

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I am relatively new to using Git and I am having some issues switching branches.

I have two branches: main and experiment. In both branches, I have a file called "admin.html". I changed its name to "admin1.html" while in my main branch. I then I switched to my experiment branch:

```
git checkout experiment
```

After switching branches, I noticed that the file name is still "admin1.html" - which it shouldn't be since I only changed the file name in my main branch, not my experiment branch.

Can someone let me know if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When you renamed the file, did you use `git mv`? What does `git status` show in each branch?

Comment: Did you commit the file name change to main? Uncommitted changes do not belong to any branch, they are local changes yet to be committed.

Comment: gotcha, i probably didn't commit first. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes when checking out between branches not all files get removed.

Try doing a clean up operation:

git clean -xdf